# Google Calendar always loads all data each time app is opened

Tags: storage, 9.0-pie, google-calendar, setup-wizard

I have a "branded" tablet with an OS derived from Android 9 (Pie). To skip the brand-related stuff like registration, I skipped the setup wizard. The device is not rooted. Debugging (via adb) is enabled, and I could customize the launcher and other settings. Everything works - all apps, all buttons - it's almost perfect. Only the Google Calendar starts with no dates and slowly downloads my entire calendar each time the app is opened. This takes a while and only works on WiFi, obviously.
I have tried clearing the storage of the Google Calendar, the in-built calendar app, and the Calendar Storage. I would like to avoid a factory reset.
Googling revealed practically nothing except for one tiny hint in [Home Screen and Recent Apps buttons don't work](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/146039/home-screen-and-recent-apps-buttons-dont-work): "Caution: Backup/sync everything before starting the setup wizard, because it might reset various things (e.g. the calendar storage (if syncing stopped before) or wifi passwords)." This mentions the calendar storage explicitly, and I did what was mentioned in the thread to skip the wizard as stated above. I believe that's when the problem started. Here is what I did back then:

```
adb shell settings put global setup_wizard_has_run 1
adb shell settings put secure user_setup_complete 1
adb shell settings put global device_provisioned 1
```

Any ideas on how I can make my Google Calendar data remain on the tablet?

**Edit**:
I tried "adb logcat" and it seems the calendar data wiping/reloading coincides with a crash of the app. It's the latest version and I have been observing this for a long time; any idea how to fix/mitigate this?

```
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.calendar, PID: 11845
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.mvu.b(PG:18)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.ioz.a(Unknown Source:6)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.das.a(Unknown Source:128)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.eji.run(Unknown Source:30)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.drs.a(PG:2)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.dax.l(PG:6)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.dax.k(PG:5)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.ddv.a(PG:65)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.diq.y(PG:71)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.diq.a(PG:2)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.android.apps.calendar.timeline.alternate.view.impl.layout.LayoutManagerImpl.e(PG:3)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ah(PG:5)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.x(PG:10)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(PG:2)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(PG:29)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:763)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2802)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2329)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1467)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7202)
10-30 12:00:24.071 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:961)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:772)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:706)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:947)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6740)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.jmm.call(Unknown Source:46)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.zly.c(PG:1)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.zla.run(PG:4)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.zlz.run(PG:1)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.ead.run(Unknown Source:4)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at cal.eac.run(Unknown Source:75)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti: Uncaught Android Crash on thread main with tid 2
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.mvu.b(PG:18)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.ioz.a(Unknown Source:6)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.das.a(Unknown Source:128)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.eji.run(Unknown Source:30)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.drs.a(PG:2)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.dax.l(PG:6)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.dax.k(PG:5)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.ddv.a(PG:65)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.diq.y(PG:71)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.diq.a(PG:2)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at com.google.android.apps.calendar.timeline.alternate.view.impl.layout.LayoutManagerImpl.e(PG:3)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ah(PG:5)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.x(PG:10)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(PG:2)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(PG:29)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:763)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2802)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2329)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1467)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7202)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:961)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:772)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:706)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:947)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6740)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.jmm.call(Unknown Source:46)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.zly.c(PG:1)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.zla.run(PG:4)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.zlz.run(PG:1)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.ead.run(Unknown Source:4)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at cal.eac.run(Unknown Source:75)
10-30 12:00:24.072 11845 11845 E CalendarUncaughtExcepti:       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: What about removing the google account from the device, reboot and then re-add the account?

Comment: @Robert: Thanks for the suggestion! I installed GApps manually and it seems it is not possible to log out from the Google account. These discussions confirm it: https://forum.xda-developers.com/amazon-fire/help/log-google-account-t3270543, https://forum.xda-developers.com/hd8-hd10/help/how-remove-google-account-firehd-82017-t4024629. I tried safe boot but to no avail.